# react native understanding textInput component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Below I have some code that works fine (its based off [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input.html) tutorial) however I don't understand why it works. Specifically I don't understand how the TextInput component knows that I want to set "thing" to the value of the TextInput. It would make more sense to me if there was something like `thing = TextInput.value` but as it is currently I don't understand it. If someone could explain to me the syntax here or direct me towards some resources on it that would be great. Please note, I have read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.htm) and the tutorial linked above but I still don't understand. Also in case this is not clear, the code below is stored in App.js and all it does is copy the current value of the TextInput to a Text component right below the TextInput.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';

export default class myapp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {thing: ''};
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{padding: 30}}>
                <TextInput placeholder="default" onChangeText={(thing) => this.setState({thing})}/>
                <Text>{this.state.thing}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically I don't understand how the TextInput component knows that
>   I want to set "thing" to the value of the TextInput.
>   So basically you have one onChange event attached so whenever you type onChange event gets triggered and set the value in the state.

```
<Text>{this.state.thing}</Text>
```

This line pick the value from state and shows it on your view.

If you want to send the value to TextInput , you can do it like this

```
<TextInput 
  placeholder="default"
  onChangeText={(thing) => this.setState({thing})}
  value= "your value"
/>
```

You  are not setting any value to TextInput here. you are just typing and updating state. which is shown to you in

```
<Text>{this.state.thing}</Text>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm still confused, to put the question differently, say the TextInput contained not value but also foo, how would it know I want to set thing to value rather than set thing to foo?

Comment: value is the key in which you can pass any value you want. if you want to pass value of foo as the value of input  pass it as value={foo}